# How do I pass a variable that contains a list to a dynamic SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a function that converts a sting list of numbers into a table of integers:

```
USE [IFRS_Temp]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[CSVToTable]    Script Date: 01/12/2019 3:36:10 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTab TABLE
   (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
    SET @InStr = REPLACE(@InStr + ',', ',,', ',')
    DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @INSTR ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @SP = PATINDEX('%,%',@INSTR)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)
   SELECT  @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '')
   INSERT INTO @TempTab(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
    RETURN
END
```

---

```
declare @listOfIDs varchar(1000);
SET @listOfIDs = '5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 28, 31, 49, 51, 59, 61'; 

select id from  [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@listOfIDs) --this code is ok5
```

The result is correct:

```
6
7
8
9
15
28
31
49
51
59
61
```

This throws an error:

```
exec('select id from  [dbo].[CSVToTable] ('+@listOfIDs+')') -- error
```

result :

> Procedure or function dbo.CSVToTable has too many arguments specified.

I need the second query because my query is dynamic.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply

```
EXECUTE ('select id from  [dbo].[CSVToTable] ('''+@listOfIDs+''')')
        declare @listOfIDs varchar(1000);
```

Or, which is the better way

```
SET @listOfIDs = '5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 28, 31, 49, 51, 59, 61'; 

EXECUTE sp_executesql N'select id from  [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@listOfIDs)',
                      N'@listOfIDs VARCHAR(1000)',
                      @listOfIDs;
```

- *Why I get this error?*

  > Procedure or function dbo.CSVToTable has too many arguments specified.

Because you really pass too much parameters, more then needed, to understand this run this query and see what you are really pass to your function

```
SELECT 'select id from  [dbo].[CSVToTable] ('+@listOfIDs+')';
```

which will return (and this is what you really trying to execute)

```
select id from  [dbo].[CSVToTable] (5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 15, 28, 31, 49, 51, 59, 61)
```

instead of (which is what you need)

```
SELECT 'select id from  [dbo].[CSVToTable] ('''+@listOfIDs+''')';
```

---

- *Ok, but why `sp_executesql` is better than `exec`?*

Simply, `EXEC` will forces you to concatenate all of your variables into one single string, that's the worst thing about it, and that makes your code fully open to **SQL injection**. See **[`Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)**, this doesn't mean that `sp_executesql` is 100% secure, but it allows for statements to be *parameterized* while `EXEC()` dosn't, therefore It’s *more secure than `EXEC` in terms of SQL injection*.

---

Finally, since you tag [[image]sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) and you don't specify the version, I suggest that you use **[`SPLIT_STRING()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function (2016+) rathar than yours, and if you don't have 2016+ version, than create your own without using `WHILE` loop to gain more good performance, cause `WHILE` loop will perform slow, thus you should avoid it.

Examples:

- **[`How to split a comma-separated value to columns`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)**
- **[`Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)**
- **[`Reaping the benefits of the Window functions in T-SQL`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/)**

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your SQL, however, let's start with the following:

```
exec('select id from  [dbo].[CSVToTable] ('+@listOfIDs+')') -- error
```

The reason for the failure is because it turns the SQL into:

```
select id from  [dbo].[CSVToTable] (1,2,3,4)
```

You can very quickly see why that's a problem. Instead, pass the value as a parameter:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT id FROM [dbo].[CSVToTable] (@IDs);', N'@IDs varchar(1000)', @IDs = @listOfIDs;
```

This'll make your code safe from injection,however,your function `CSVToTable` uses a `WHILE`,which means it's going to perform badly. If you're using SQL Server 2016+ you have access to `SPLIT_SPLIT`. It'll be way faster than a iterative process.

If not, I recommend having a look at [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) for SQL Server 2008, or [DelimitedSplit8k_lead](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/) for SQL Server 2012 & 2014. You'll find a them to be far better performance wise.