# I used in clause but give type conversion error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I used a dynamic sql query and prevent sql injection
i want used ( **@clientIds** ) instead of (**'+@clientIds+'** )

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--exec test '1,2'
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @clientIds varchar(Max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sSQL  nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX);
    Select @sSQL=N'select * from tblClient WITH (NOLOCK) Where clientID in ( @clientIds )'
    SET @params = N'@clientIds NVARCHAR(50)';
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sSQL, @params, @clientIds;
END
```

Comment: How does the data in `@clientIds` variable looks like?

Comment: `NOLOCK` means "read dirty data while taking excessive locks". It won't fix any problems you may have. In this case, probably because `ClientID` isn't covered by an index

Comment: @clientids like (1,2,3)

Comment: I won't use a dynamic SQL since I can. Why you need so? Why not just pass a table valued parameter?

Comment: if passed table value there is sql injection problem

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you targeting? You can't pass multiple values in a parameter in any case, nor use `IN @clientIds` and have it treated as a list of values. You can pass a table-valued parameter and join with it. SQL Server 2016 and later has `STRING_SPLIT` which allows you to split the values and join with the results

Comment: @AshishMaurya no there isn't. It's the *exact* opposite. It's your current code that's vulnerable to SQL Injection. In fact, that's what caused the error in the first place

Comment: sql server version is 2012

Comment: @AshishMaurya in that case the only way to avoid SQL injection is to use a table-valued parameter, or use the XML-based string splitting technique to convert the list of IDs to a result set of IDs.

Comment: A better idea is to *NOT* use a stored procedure and use an ORM like EF or Dapper create a safe query. There would be no SQL injection risk if the list of IDs was created from a `List<int>` on the client

Comment: if run like this exec test '1,2);drop table tblclient--' then it delete table 
so iwant used like (@cliendid) not ('+@clientid+')

Answer (score 0):

Your SP can be like

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @clientIds varchar(Max)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SQL  NVARCH(max) = N'SELECT * FROM [tblClient] WHERE [clientID] IN(' + @clientIds + N');';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

But, that won't prevent SQL Injection as it may be in the parameter `'1,2;DELETE * FROM tblClient;`.

I would use a **[`Table-Valued Parameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)** instead as

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS TABLE (Id INT);

Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
  @IDs MyType READONLY
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM [tblClient] 
    WHERE [clientID] IN(SELECT Id FROM @IDs);
```

OR

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
  @IDs MyType READONLY
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT C.*
    FROM [tblClient] C INNER JOIN @IDs Ids
    ON C.clientID = Ids.Id;
```

Also, check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54159477/6426692) for a situation like yours.

Comment: That's what the OP wants to avoid as it's wide open to SQL injection

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Under construction :)

Comment: the OP edited the question multiple times. `IN(' + @clientIds + N')` was the original query