# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' and f.FUNCTION_ID= CAST(' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to make the procedure where I can get the data from MS SQL. Here I am getting the error

**Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GET_FUNCTIONS, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 33]
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' and f.FUNCTION_ID in '' to data type int.**

```
    CREATE procedure [dbo].[GET_FUNCTIONS]
    @Function_Id int,
    @EntityId int,
    @OrderBy varchar(10)
    as
    begin
    declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
    if(@Function_Id=0 AND @EntityId=0)
    set @Sql = 'select                                                        
    f.Function_Code,f.FUNCTION_ID,f.EntityId,be.ENTITY_SHORT_NAME,f.FUNCTION_NAME,
    f.FUNCTION_DESC,f.CREATED_DATE,f.MODIFIED_DATE from FUNCTIONS f 
    inner join BusinessEntity be on f.EntityId=be.ID
    WHERE f.ACTIVE=1 '

    if(@Function_Id!=0)
    set @Sql += ' and f.FUNCTION_ID in ''' + @Function_Id + ''''
    if(@EntityId!=0)
    set @Sql += ' and f.EntityId = cast('+convert(varchar(12) ,@EntityId)+') '

    set @Sql += ' order by FUNCTION_ID '+ @OrderBy
    print @Sql
    end
    GO
```

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/54159434/6426692

Comment: Fix the injection issue, fix the problem. **NEVER** inject parameters into a dynamic statement, parametrise it, and quote your dynamic objects *properly*. [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: What is _@function_id_? An int. What happens when you concatenate an int with varchar - which are 2 expressions with different datatypes? One of them is converted to the other based on well defined rules. Int has higher precedence, hence the error. Fix your concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I have got the answer by my own.

I have removed `if(@Function_Id=0 AND @EntityId=0)` and changed the data type of @Function_Id and @EntityId to varchar(100), so solved all errors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm, making a few guesses here, which I add some comments about, however, this should be what you are after. I firstly ensure that I parametrise the values, but also validate and quote the value of `@OrderBy`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_FUNCTIONS] @Function_Id int =NULL, --Instead of passing 0as "select all" use NULL
                                       @EntityId int = NULL, --Instead of passing 0as "select all" use NULL
                                       @OrderBy nvarchar(4) --guessing this is mean to be ASC or DESC?
AS
BEGIN

    IF @OrderBy NOT IN (N'ASC','DESC')
        --Error is not ASC or DESC
        THROW 51473, N'@OrderBy can only have a value of ''ASC'' or ''DESC''.',16; --51473 was a random error number; you can use one that is appropriate for your environment.

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT f.Function_Code,' + + @CRLF +
               N'       f.FUNCTION_ID,' + + @CRLF +
               N'       f.EntityId,' + + @CRLF +
               N'       be.ENTITY_SHORT_NAME,' + + @CRLF +
               N'       f.FUNCTION_NAME,' + + @CRLF +
               N'       f.FUNCTION_DESC,' + + @CRLF +
               N'       f.CREATED_DATE,' + + @CRLF +
               N'       f.MODIFIED_DATE' + + @CRLF +
               N'FROM FUNCTIONS f' + + @CRLF +
               N'     INNER JOIN BusinessEntity be ON f.EntityId = be.ID' + + @CRLF +
               N'WHERE f.ACTIVE = 1';

    IF (@Function_Id IS NOT NULL)
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @CRLF + N'  AND f.FUNCTION_ID = @Function_Id'

    IF (@EntityId IS NOT NULL)
        SET @SQL = @SQL + @CRLF + N'  AND f.EntityId = @EntityId'

    SET @SQL = @SQL + @CRLF +
               N'ORDER BY F.FUNCTION_ID ' + QUOTENAME(@OrderBy) + N';'

    --PRINT @SQL; --Uncomment for debugging.
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Function_Id int, @EntityId int', @Function_Id, @EntityId;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Good Suggestions but no help as it is not showing the result if I am executing the procedure.

Comment: then there are no results in the dataset, @ttr, the the resulting value opf `@SQL` is `NULL`. Use the inbuilt debugger i gave you

Comment: I have data in table but after passing the values it is not showing the result.

Comment: The debugger is showing the exact query which I have to run but no values in `@Function_Id` and `@EntityId`.

Comment: No, it won't, @ttr, but *you* know what you've passed for `@Function_ID` and `@Entity_ID`

Comment: I would suggest you to try from your end and you will get the answer of what I am saying.

Comment: I can't, I don't have access to your instance, @ttr and you provided no sample data or objects.