# IN with Varchar is not working sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below code is throwing error

```
declare @test varchar(100)='20,201,202,288'
SELECT * from Business where Businessid in (@test)
```

i.e.
    Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '20,201,202,288' to data type int.

how can i make it working, i'm not getting, might be my mind is not able think any more..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable that contains a list to a dynamic SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159434/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-that-contains-a-list-to-a-dynamic-sql-query)

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `string_split()`:

```
select *
from Business
where Businessid in (select value from string_split(@test, ','));
```

You are confusing a string with a list of values in an `in` list.  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `string_split` in `SQL Server 2016 and later versions` only so I choose dynamic query for any version with more flexibility

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(100) = '20,201,202,288', @sql VARCHAR(250)

SET @sql = '
SELECT * 
FROM Business 
WHERE Businessid IN (' + @test + ')'

EXEC(@sql)
```